# How tensorflow LSTM feed parameters to LSTM circuit?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

So I am implementing the LSTM and i have some doubts , In LSTM papers and other theory i read that LSTM takes 4 input so Here is a toy example with LSTM circuit and its taking a simple array [1,0,1] now this array is passing to each 4 inputs gates like this :
[image]

Now there is no problem i got the theory part , Problem is when i try to implement LSTM in tensorflow then its takes input in this format [[[x,x,x,x]]] and gives output [[x,x]] now i am confuse between coding and theory part , I want to understand how tensorflow taking the input and how this format is going to feed into LSTM circuit , How its processing ?
[image]

I also found this explanation very helpful but that is also in theory terms , I want to understand the input format meaning of tensorflow for LSTM which is [[[x,x,x,x]]] and what is output format meaning

so here is toy example in tensorflow

```
with tf.variable_scope('one_cell') as scope:
    # One cell RNN input_dim (4) -> output_dim (2)
    hidden_size = 2
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=hidden_size)
    print(cell.output_size, cell.state_size)

    x_data = np.array([[h]], dtype=np.float32) # x_data = [[[1,0,0,0]]]
    pp.pprint(x_data)
    outputs, _states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x_data, dtype=tf.float32)

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    pp.pprint(outputs.eval())
```

output

```
2 2
array([[[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]], dtype=float32)
array([[[ 0.28406101,  0.53163123]]], dtype=float32)
```

Now what is tensorflow lstm doing with `[[[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]]`  and what is the result representing, what `[[[ 0.28406101,  0.53163123]]]` mean? what it's representing ?? its a prediction or what ?

Comment: Well it all depends what is your input,time series or categorical variable or ..You should read https://towardsdatascience.com/lstm-by-example-using-tensorflow-feb0c1968537